# How can I get the link from href in "a" with class name by using python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I've tried to get the link from google map which the element is:

```
<div class="something1">
  <span class="something2"></span>
  <a data-track-id="Google Map" href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir//11111/@22222" target="_blank" class="something3">Google Map</a>
</div>
```

which I only would like to get https://www.google.com/maps/dir//11111/@22222

My code is

```
 gpslocation = []
 for gps in (secondpage_parser.find("a", {"data-track-id":"Google Map"})):
     gpslocation.append(gps.attrs["href"])
```

I'm using 2 url pages (main and secondpage) for scraping a blog website which this is in the secondpage. The other info like Story-Title or Author Name work as it appears as text so I can use `get_text()`.

But this case, I could not get the link after `href`. Please help.

Ps. In the case I only want Latitude and Longtitude in the link which are (11111 and 22222) is there is a way to use `str.rplit`?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
secondpage_parser.find("a", {"data-track-id":"Google Map"})['href']
```

Comment: Thanks! But there was no link after I run it. Am I going to the right way? The code I put: gpslocation = [] for gps in (secondpage_parser.find("a", {"data-track-id":"Google Map"})['href']): gpslocation.append(gps.attrs["href"])

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `soup.find(...)['href']` for finding all links with an href or `soup.find_all('a' ... , href=True)`for all links
2. Yes you can use split to only get lat and long

   - First split on `//` and get the latest `[-1]`
   - Then split on `/@` to get both lat and long

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div class="something1">
  <span class="something2"></span>
  <a data-track-id="Google Map" href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir//11111/@22222" target="_blank" class="something3">Google Map</a>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
for gps in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    href = gps['href']
    print(href)
    lati, longi = href.split("//")[-1].split('/@')
    print(lati)
    print(longi)
```

Comment: Thank you! But it turned out that the url link was from another class. How should I specify that I want to get it? Or is there any detail I need to give you more? The code I've tried 1) for gps in secondpage_parser.find_all('a',{"data-track-id":"Google Map"}, href=True): href = gps['href'] print(href) 2) for gps in secondpage_parser.find_all('a', href=True): href = gps['href'] print(href) but both didn't work